# How to pull channel entry data from Playa Links

Tags: channel-entries, add-on, playa

So have you heard about the new [Playa Links add-on](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/playa-links)? It's kind of great, showing you when entry A has selected entry X in its Playa field. But how do you pull the data from entry A into entry X? Is it the same way as pulling it from X to A?

Is this unclear?

Comment: Are you referring to the [Playa Links add-on](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/playa-links)?

Comment: Yes, that's the one. I should've linked it myself.

Comment: By "pull the data" do you mean "view the linked entries"?

Comment: No, I mean pull data out of the linked entry and display it.

Answer (score 1):

[Playa Links](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/playa-links) is just a convenience fieldtype for displaying relationships within the EE control panel entry screen.

To actually display your data in your templates, you have to use Playa's [field tags or module tags](http://docs.pixelandtonic.com/playa/).